# Regular expression to convert css px to scss rem

Tags: css, regex, intellij-idea, sass

As part of an exercise to convert all the existing css to scss, I need to convert all the `px` to `rem`

```
#olpPredefinedInputs {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

**to be converted to**

```
#olpPredefinedInputs {
    margin-top: rem(5px);
    margin-left: rem(35px);
    margin-bottom: rem(30px);
    margin-right: rem(15px);
    font-size: rem(11px);
}
```

I tried various regex's on my IDE (Intellij), however I could not find a regex that can do this task. I am not in favour of scripts  for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex pattern: `\d+px`

Replace pattern `rem($0)`

However, I'm not sure about the regex implementation of your IDE

Comment: You're supposed to keep the "px" too

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
:\s(.*?px)
```

Substitution:

```
: rem($1)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/5)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get a `px` value to `rem` you can use this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11187-px2rwd) on IntellJ